# Два определения при одном существительном: единственное или множественное число?

Tags: морфология

Доброго времени суток уважаемые форумчане.

*Сбрызгиваем рис рыбным и соевым соусом.*

или

*Сбрызгиваем рис рыбным и соевым соусами.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оба варианта возможны.

Обращаемся в Розенталю:
Единственное число существительного  употребляется

> 4) **если перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне
>   связаны**, например, в сочетаниях терминологического характера: ср.: в
>   правой и левой руке (половине, стороне и т. п.); оперное и балетное
>   искусство; промышленный и аграрный переворот; учащиеся среднего и
>   старшего школьного возраста; программы для восьмилетней и средней
>   школы (как системы образования); в старославянском и древнерусском
>   книжном языке; глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида
>   (действительного и страдательного залога, настоящего и прошедшего
>   времени, изъявительного и сослагательного наклонения, первого и
>   второго спряжения и т. п.); существительные мужского, женского и
>   среднего рода (первого и второго склонения, единственного и
>   множественного числа); местоимения первого и второго лица; вирусный и
>   простой грипп; головной и спинной мозг; война Алой и Белой розы.
>
> Ср. также: Город был открыт для ветров с северной и восточной стороны.

http://rozental.gramatik.ru/xliv-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-i-prilozheniy/ss-194-dva-opredeleniya-pri-odnom-sushchestvitelnom

Но если Вам **важно подчеркнуть, что  было два соуса** , то ставьте существительное во множественном числе.

Я бы поставила в единственном.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос о согласовании в числе возникает в том случае, если несколько однородных определений [*рыбный и соевый*] относятся к одному определяемому существительному [*соус*], причем определения указывают на разновидности предметов.

**Единственное число** подчеркивает внутреннюю связь определяемых предметов, например: *существительное мужского и женского рода; глаголы первого и второго спряжения; в правой и левой половине дома* и т. п.
Форма **множественного числа** определяемого существительного подчеркивает наличие нескольких предметов, например: *немецкий и французский языки; филологический и исторический факультеты; старшая и младшая дочери* и т. п.
Если определяемое существительное **стоит впереди определений**, то оно ставится в форме множественного числа, например: *спряжения первое и второе; виды совершенный и несовершенный.*

Существительное в предложении стоит **после** определений, поэтому автор может выбрать любое число (это не будет ошибкой).
Если акцент делается на количестве соусов в каком-то рецепте (предположим, что в предыдущем был только один), то лучше использовать множественное число. Если же это одиночный рассказ, то я бы предпочла единственное число.

**Рис и овощи готовятся отдельно, с добавлением соевого и рыбного соуса** (из рецепта).

[Согласование определений с определяемым словом](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-167.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант не до конца ясен (непосвящённый может подумать, что соус один и тот же - рыбный и соевый одновременно), а второй - излишне формален (при том, что начато предложение в стиле "мы с вами"). Поэтому стилистически лучше "**...рыбным, (а) *затем* соевым соусом**"; это одновременно исключает возможность множественного числа.